# How to install Google play services in Dragonboard 410c?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, development-environment, dragonboard

I want to install google play services and other google apps in my dragonboard 410c board to run and install other apps like YuppTV and YouTube . If any one knows the way of installing, please let me know. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Install Google Playstore on Android Dragonboard410c](https://discuss.96boards.org/t/install-google-playstore-on-android/917) forum as some of the users were successful in installing Google services on it.

- Install Google Play service.apk, GoogleLoginServices.apk, GoogleServiceFramework.apk and Google play store.apk\
- Copy Google Play service.apk,GoogleServiceFramework.apk and Google play store.apk into the DragonBoard "/system/priv-app/" directory and restart the system
- Mount the system directory as read-write
  To mount use the commands . get root access. go to adb shell

  mount -o remount,rw /system

  to copy use:

  #adb push file.apk /system/priv-app/